# Joining datasets in nearest time R

Tags: r, join

I am trying to join 2 data sets with the closest TimeDate(POSTIXct format).

Indeed, some of the DateTime are properly matching and others are different by 5 min.

```
(df1) //// every 5 min with specific time points
# A tibble: 6 × 3
  TimeDate            TimeDateAnimal        Event
  <dttm>              <chr>                 <dbl>
1 2015-03-01 00:55:00 2015-03-01 00:55:00 G     1
**2 2015-03-01 03:40:00 2015-03-01 03:40:00 G     1
3 2015-03-01 03:45:00 2015-03-01 03:45:00 G     1**
4 2015-03-01 13:35:00 2015-03-01 13:35:00 G     1
5 2015-03-01 18:45:00 2015-03-01 18:45:00 G     1
6 2015-03-01 19:10:00 2015-03-01 19:10:00 G     1


> (df2) /// every 10 min
A tibble: 52 × 3
   TimeDate            TimeDateAnimal        Temperature
   <dttm>              <chr>                       <dbl>
1  2015-03-01 00:05:00 2015-03-01 00:05:00 G    38.52000
2  2015-03-01 00:15:00 2015-03-01 00:15:00 G    38.65333
3  2015-03-01 00:25:00 2015-03-01 00:25:00 G    38.78667
4  2015-03-01 00:35:00 2015-03-01 00:35:00 G    38.86000
5  2015-03-01 00:45:00 2015-03-01 00:45:00 G    38.92667
6  2015-03-01 00:55:00 2015-03-01 00:55:00 G    38.99333
..
**34  2015-03-01 03:35:00 2015-03-01 03:35:00 G    38.80000
35  2015-03-01 03:45:00 2015-03-01 03:45:00 G    38.80000**
```

I would like this output:

```
Merge df:
   TimeDate            TimeDateAnimal        Temperature    Event
   <dttm>              <chr>                       <dbl>    <dbl>
1  2015-03-01 00:05:00 2015-03-01 00:05:00 G    38.52000     NA
2  2015-03-01 00:15:00 2015-03-01 00:15:00 G    38.65333     NA
3  2015-03-01 00:25:00 2015-03-01 00:25:00 G    38.78667     NA
4  2015-03-01 00:35:00 2015-03-01 00:35:00 G    38.86000     NA
5  2015-03-01 00:45:00 2015-03-01 00:45:00 G    38.92667     NA
6  2015-03-01 00:55:00 2015-03-01 00:55:00 G    38.99333     NA
..
**34  2015-03-01 03:35:00 2015-03-01 03:35:00 G    38.80000     1
35  2015-03-01 03:45:00 2015-03-01 03:45:00 G    38.80000      1**
```

I tried fuzzyjoin, data.table but I always get extra raw instead of merging by the nearest TimeDate
`Test<- merge(df1, df2, by = "TimeDate", roll = "nearest",all = T)`

```
#head(Test, n=15)
      TimeDate    TimeDateAnimal.x Event    TimeDateAnimal.y Temperature
10 2015-03-01 00:45:00       <NA>    NA 2015-03-01 00:45:00 G    38.92667
11 2015-03-01 00:55:00 2015-03-01 00:55:00 G     1      <NA>          NA
12 2015-03-01 00:55:00       <NA>    NA 2015-03-01 00:55:00 G    38.99333
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you give more detail? example of your code, you data bese and what you try to do?

Comment: @LéoHenry, please find additional detail. Thanks

Comment: This is really hard to read, and I cannot access your data. I need a dput to try anything. Otherwise I can just tell you to find common ID and use a left_join() of the dplyr library.

Comment: Hi! The issue it is there is no common ID: The common ID could be the TimeDate but some are 12:00, 12:10, 12:20... and the others are 12:06,  12:01... I would then like to merge them based on the closest TimeDate every 10minutes - ie: 12:06 will match with 12:10 whereas 12:01 will match with 12:00.